# Is "SFTP" and "FTP over SSL" a same thing?

Tags: ssl, ftp, sftp, ftps

I need to write a program to send some files to an SFTP server. I googled, but found there is similar thing called "FTP over SSL".

Are they the same?

Answer (score 14):

Wikipedia explains the differences: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS

> **FTPS (also known as FTP Secure and FTP-SSL)** is an extension to the commonly used File Transfer Protocol (FTP) that adds support for the
>   Transport Layer Security (TLS) and the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
>   cryptographic protocols.
>
> **FTPS should not be confused with the SSH File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)**, an incompatible secure file transfer subsystem for the
>   Secure Shell (SSH) protocol. It is also different from Secure FTP, the
>   practice of tunneling FTP through an SSH connection.

Comment: Just note that as *Secure FTP* is often called both: SFTP and FTPS. If someone tells you to communicate over Secure FTP ask him immediately what he/she means to avoid confusion;)