# SSH host key fingerprint does not match pattern C# WinSCP

Tags: c#, ftp, winscp, ftps, winscp-net

I am trying to connect to an FTPS server using C# via WinSCP and I am getting this error:

> SSH host key fingerprint ... does not match pattern ...

After tons of research, I believe is has something to do with the length of the key. The key I got from WinSCP when connected using its interface under "Server and protocol information" is
`xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`  but the ones I saw in the example is shorter like this `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`

Can someone please help and offer me any pointer to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
string winscpPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.exe";
string username = "User123";
string password = "abc1234";
string ftpSite = "192.168.5.110";
string localPath = "C:\\Users\\ttom\\Documents";
string remoteFTPDirectory = "/Usr/thisfolder";
string sshKey = "1b:68:10:80:77:c6:65:91:51:31:5t:65:1c:g6:13:20:39:g8:d8:6d";
Boolean winSCPLog = true;
string winSCPLogPath = "C:\\Users\\ttom\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\WebApplication1\\WebApplication1";

SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = ftpSite,
    UserName = username,
    Password = password,
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = sshKey
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // WinSCP .NET assembly must be in GAC to be used with SSIS,
    // set path to WinSCP.exe explicitly, if using non-default path.
    session.ExecutablePath = winscpPath;
    session.DisableVersionCheck = true;

    if (winSCPLog)
    {
        session.SessionLogPath = @winSCPLogPath + @"ftplog.txt";
        session.DebugLogPath = @winSCPLogPath + @"debuglog.txt";
    }

    // Connect
    session.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0); // two minutes
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

    session.GetFiles(remoteFTPDirectory + "/" +
        "test.txt", localPath, false, transferOptions);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you have a WinSCP client, and are able to connect to the FTP site. WinSCP has a nice "code generation" function.

1. Connect first
2. Select Session > Generate session URL/code

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I did not know this existed and it is most excellent!

Comment: @DanielWilliams I have tried that but the I got the Error "WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: The key-exchange algorithm diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 was not verified!"

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing the same issue. But after trying some different pattern, The following pattern Worked for me :

1. Add ssh-rsa as 1st part
2. Add 2048 ( key length in bits) as the 2nd part
3. Remove SHA256: if you have that in the key you have obtained
4. Keep only the key part, Do not separate them in the set of 2, keep the key as it is as you have obtained from the command ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub

Example: ssh-rsa 2048 N48XXXXH2x9W1ZIFXXXXXXXX6p3UqI6kGA8BbO1XXX

Comment: Using FileZilla to show the fingerprint values, adding a trailing "=" to the fingerprint was necessary (in addition to the steps you clearly explain) for the WinSCP connection to work.

Comment: Removing the "SHA256:" did the trick for me when using WinSCPnet.dll from PowerShell.

Answer (score 4):

You are connecting using SFTP (over SSH) in the code, but using FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL) in GUI.

These are two [completely different protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8599862/850848).

Use [`Protocol = Protocol.Ftp`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#protocol) and enable TLS/SSL using [`FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#ftpsecure).

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit,
    HostName = ftpSite,
    UserName = username,
    Password = password,
};
```

An equivalent of `SshHostKeyFingerprint` for FTPS is [`TlsHostCertificateFingerprint`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#tlshostcertificatefingerprint). But you need to use it only when the TLS/SSL certificate is not signed by a trusted authority (e.g. a self signed certificate).

---

The easiest is to have [WinSCP GUI generate code](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) for you.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same error. In my case I discovered the PC that I copied the SSH Fingerprint key from was running a newer version of WinSCP than the one I had on my development PC.

Updating the WinSCP.exe and WinSCPnet.DLL files on my Dev PC fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar task. Have you tried prefixing 'ssh-rsa' to your fingerprint string?

Everything seems to be working on my end so that leads me to believe that there are two things that **could** be going on here.

1. You could be missing part of your authentication string:

   ```
   string SshHostKeyFingerpring = "ssh-rsa XXXX 1b:68:10:80:77:c6:65:91:51:31:5t:65:1c:g6:13:20:39:g8:d8:6d";
   ```

   and/or
2. You are using two protocols. SFTP and FTPS