# ftp_ssl_connect from Apache/php is failing while command-line sftp is working

Tags: php, apache, sftp

server I can run the command: `sftp user@192.168.0.130`
But when I test this PHP command it is unavailable to connect to the sftp.

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect("192.168.0.130", 22) or die("Could not connect to 192.168.0.130");
```

Why is it like this? I use an Ubuntu Server 15.04 and Apache2.

Comment: read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SFTP is not FTP over TLS/SSL.

So the PHP FTP/SSL client will fail to talk to the remote SSH server.

See

- [Is "SFTP" and "Ftp over SSL" a same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8599862/850848)
- [How to SFTP with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4689540/850848)