# "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format" FluentFTP error when connecting to SFTP server

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, fluentftp

I am trying to connect to  SFTP server to download some files. The code is written in C# and I am using FluentFTP to connect to the FTP. Client has given port as 22. But when I try the following code, I am getting the error

> The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format

Anyone who worked on FluentFTP can suggest me what I am missing in my code.

```
FtpClient fclient = new FtpClient("xxx.yyy.com", "username", "password"); 
fclient.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Implicit;
fclient.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
fclient.Port = 22;                 
fclient.Connect();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FluentFTP is FTP(S) client.

SFTP is a completely different protocol. See also [Is "SFTP" and "FTP over SSL" a same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8599862/850848)

You cannot use FluentFTP to connect to an SFTP server. You have to use another SFTP library, see [SFTP Libraries for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530330/850848).